# How to write a more concise for-of loop

Tags: javascript, for-of-loop

I have a `for`-`of` loop which goes like this:

```
for(const val of someArray[0].properties) {
 // some processing;
}
```

Now for some reason if `someArray[0].properties` is undefined, the loop breaks, saying:

> Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

If I try to use the `!!` shorthand for boolean operators:

```
for (const val of !!someArray[0].properties && someArray[0].properties) {
}
```

it fails again.

The only solution I could come up with was:

```
if(someArray[0].properties){ // this will check for that undefined issue
    for(const val of someArray[0].properties) {
     // some processing;
    }
}
```

**Is there a more concise solution than this?**

Comment: for(let val of someArr){  console.log(val); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more concise:

```
for (const val of someArray[0].properties || []) {
  // some processing
}
```

Basically, if `someArray[0].properties` is undefined, the empty array is used instead of it throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 that work for me.  I prefer the 3rd loop as it's clearer.

Setting someArray.properties to null or undefined results in no loop and no error.

```html
<script>
var someArray = [{ properties : [1,2] }]

for(const val of someArray[0].properties ? someArray[0].properties : []) {
   console.log("1")
}

var props = someArray[0].properties
for(const val of props ? props : []) {
   console.log("2")
}

for (const val of someArray[0].properties || []) {
  console.log("3")
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
someArray[0].properties && Object.keys(someArray[0].properties).forEach(function(key){
    var val = someArray[0].properties[key];
    ...
})
```

alternatively

```
for (const val of someArray[0].properties ? someArray[0].properties : {}) {
}
```

Comment: The second option fails with `(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best, simple and clear way is:

```
if (typeof someArray[0].properties !== 'undefined') {
  for (const val of someArray[0].properties) {
      //
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think so too. I thought probably there is more concise way out there. Seems like there wasn't

Comment: You can cheat with some parts of this code, but with purpose to have simple and robust code this one is pretty not bad...

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach is using `(maybe_null || {}).property`, e.g.:

```
var empty = {};
((someArray || empty)[0] || empty).properties || empty
```

It's more concise if you use `e` instead of `empty`. :-) Or by using `{}` instead of a variable, which may increase the runtime cost by a tiny fraction.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most clean solution but I guess it is what you're looking for:

```js
//init
const someArray = [{
  properties: {
    a:'1',
    b: 2,
    c:undefined
  }
}];

const props = someArray[0].properties;

for (const val of Object.keys(props).filter(x => props[x]).map(x => {
  const a = {};
  a[x] = props[x];
  return a;
})) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

*Btw. I would not use this approach because it's kinda unreadable. Imo Vladimir Kovpak's answer is pretty straightforward which ends up in a much more maintainable code.*